# npm run-script flow is not working

Tags: npm, react-native, flowtype

I created a react native project, and I want to enable flow for my project.

I have flow-bin installed by

```
npm install --save flow-bin
```

However, it returns

```
missing script: flow
```

when I run

```
npm run-script flow
```

Anyone got any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Is the script defined in your package.json?

Comment: No, I expected npm install would add the script automatically, but it didn't. But it solved now. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm run-script flow` will not execute the `flow` command, but will just look into the `scripts` entry in the `package.json` file and execute the command under the `flow` entry (see the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) for more information). This has the advantage that it will include binaries located in your dependencies (a.k.a. binaries inside the `node_modules` folder), which is something you usually do not have in your `$PATH`, avoiding the need to configure that for every project. Make sure that your `package.json` looks something like this:

```
//...
"scripts":{
    //...
    "flow": "flow; test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2"
}
//...
```

Source: [docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Comment: Also, have a look at the second link for more information on how to set Flow up, particularly the `.flowconfig` file.

Comment: Work now, Thanks!

Comment: Tried this but still the same issue: missing script:flow

Comment: Have you checked that it is installed?

Comment: What's the "test $? -eq 0 -o $? -eq 2" component do?

Comment: @Casebash it checks the exit code of the `flow` call (in a shell `$?` is a variable that stores the exit of the previous command). It checks if it is equal to 0 or 2. 0 means normal behavior, but unfortunately I can't remember why also 2 is considered a correct termination, and I can't find in the documentation what the possible exit codes are. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Add "flow": "flow" as a new entry under "scripts" in your package.json file:

```
  ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  ...
```

The tutorials I was following seem to skip this step but the Facebook github repo has it: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-flow

Comment: anchor is broken in your link actual link is https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-flow